# Handling ceiling effect of dependent variable in mixed models (R lmer)

Tags: r, scaling, lme4, ceil

I would like to ask around who has any experience with handling ceiling effects of the dependent variable in linear mixed effects models. I found this paper here suggesting results for models outside mixed modeling ( https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2778494/ ) but it would be very convenient to find options within the lme4 (lmer) package in R. Any ideas? Can this problem be solved with generalized mixed models by adjusting the link function? How?